# If you use Inversion of Control, what alternatives to obfuscated function calls exist?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, functions, anti-patterns, inversion-of-control

Consider a class that follows the [obfuscated function call anti-pattern](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0?t=165). I've also seen these called "stupid classes". The definition of such a class is that it only has one public method and one public constructor. As the name suggests, such classes should "just be a function". For illustration purposes, here is a such a class in C# terms. In the interest of keeping this question accessible, I've avoided using any special C# tricks or syntax.

```csharp
public class ObfuscatedFunctionCall
{
    private int _number1;
    private int _number2;
    private ITalkToSever _ServerTalker;

    // Constructor.
    public ObfuscatedFunctionCall(int number1, int number2, ITalkToSever ServerTalker)
    {
        _number1 = number1;
        _number2 = number2;
        _ServerTalker = ServerTalker;
    }

    // The one method.
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Send _number1 and _number2 to a server.
    }
}
```

This should, of course, "just be a function" that takes in the two numbers as arguments and sends them to the server which is itself represented by a third argument. **My problem is that I believe that Inversion of Control is incompatible with making this "just a function"**.

My preferred method for achieving Inversion of Control is Dependency Injection achieved via Constructor Injection. In other words, I believe that `ObfuscatedFunctionCall` should implement an `IObfuscatedFunctionCall` interface.

```
public interface IObfuscatedFunctionCall
{
    void Execute();
}

public class ObfuscatedFunctionCall : IObfuscatedFunctionCall
{
   // Same code as before, only the above changed.
}
```

and that consumers of `ObfuscatedFunctionCall` should take an object of type `IObfuscatedFunctionCall` as an argument to their constructor. The primary benefits of this design are late binding and loose coupling; Being able to replace `ObfuscatedFunctionCall` with any other object of type `IObfuscatedFunctionCall` at run time enables benefits such as unit testing of volatile dependencies.

**Can Inversion of Control, and thus benefits such as late binding and loose coupling, be achieved if `ObfuscatedFunctionCall` is "just a function" rather than an interface-backed instance class?**

I've considered and rejected the following approaches to make this class be "just a function" while still using it for Constructor Injection:

1. It can't be a static class. You can't pass a static class in a constructor, so you get very tight coupling to the static class in your consumers and the static class can't be used for late binding.
2. It can't be any sort of C# function-holding object like a `Func`. These are almost as good as using instance class, but they have a major flaw. If you put a `Func` in a consumer's constructor, then the consumer must know how many arguments the `Func` takes in and their types. This is not true of an interface-backed instance class; If I take in an `IObfuscatedFunctionCall` in a consumer's constructor, then my consumer never needs to know if I've added more arguments to `ObfuscatedFunctionCall`'s constructor.
3. It can't be a delegate. Those have the exact same faults as `Func`s.
4. I can't imagine any way to make this a static method without encountering the same faults as what you get with static classes.

In conclusion, I think that an interface-backed instance class is the only option that allows Inversion of Control. What alternatives have I overlooked? Is C#'s lack of first-class functions a relevant constraint? I never see Clojure or Python people have this issue, so I'm ready to accept non-C# answers.

Comment: Isn't this what https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/icommand-interface-in-mvvm/ is for? (that adds CanExecute as well)

Comment: Can someone please explain why this question keeps getting voted down?

Comment: @GregBurghardt didn't downvote but on first sight: it asks impossible things and realizes it in the last paragraph.

Comment: That's a fair point, however I do not believe it is asking impossible things, providing a language supports closures, especially given Clojure and Python as reference languages, which the OP does not believe have this problem -- and that's because those languages readily support closures, and programmers readily use them as a matter of practice.

Comment: If you do DI then chances are there is some interface involved. Then this is no longer an obfuscated method but a strategy pattern. Dynamic languages get less hung up on this because you don't have to use interfaces and because DI containers are less common there. However, common Python linters will definitely complain if a class only has a single method.

Comment: The obvious answer is to inject a delegate. I do not understand your objection. Obviously your class must know the function's arguments and return type or it can't call it. If there are "constructor arguments" that set up some sort of state that means we are not talking about an obfuscated function, which is stateless.

Comment: Is not the question language dependant? If yes, I wonder if it's not yet another "*why my programming language sucks at doing what other programming language do effortlessly?*"

Comment: you mean like this? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736070/how-to-use-funct-in-built-in-dependency-injection

Comment: @Laiv I'm unsure if other languages do this effortlessly. Those that do seem to have weaker contracts than what an interface gives. If you can think of a language with contracts as strong as C#'s interfaces that also does this effortlessly, then I'd be interested to see it. Maybe Haskell or F#?

Comment: @Ewan That question seems to be about registering a `Func` in a DI Container. I'm unsure how that addresses the question of replacing a class.

Comment: @J.Mini replace the class with a function `constructor(Func<T1,T2,TReturn> func)` Inject with modified DI? I'm not sure i understand your objections

Comment: @Ewan You might be on to something. Feel free to write that up as an answer.

Comment: Can you clarify your objections to `Func`, delegates, IAction, ICommand etc which all seem like answers to your problem? on first read it seems like you are just having probs using DI and Func, but as you write you seem to rule out all the c# ways of passing functions around?

Comment: @Ewan My objection to using a `Func` is that the consumer of a `Func` needs to know its input parameters. This is unlike using an interface-backed class which is passed in to a consumer via the consumer's constructor, because I can change the class's constructor without the consumer knowing.

Comment: ok, I think I see, but. if you want a function with no parameters, you can just pass in an `Action` How you setup what that Action does is done outsize of the class that calls the action, or Execute method in both cases

Comment: I've added my answer, but it seems trivial when you boil it down. I think really your problem is something different

Comment: *because I can change the class's constructor without the consumer knowing* If your class has a constructor that takes arguments, it is not a class that wraps an obfuscated function. An obfuscated function has no state of its own. If it requires state, you need a state container, so you need a class; that is unavoidable. So... again... *use a delegate*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "As the name suggests, such classes should "just be a function"."_

Hard disagree. The lifetime of the constructor parameters might be different from those passed via the method. You cannot correctly assert that *all* instances of this should just be a function.

At best, I'll agree that when this pattern occurs, it's worth it to evaluate **if** this can be refactored to being just a method.

> Can Inversion of Control, and thus benefits such as late binding and loose coupling, be achieved if ObfuscatedFunctionCall is "just a function" rather than an interface-backed instance class?

No. "Just a function" omits the inherent "...and not a wrapped object around said method", and it's the latter part that inherently argues against instantiation, ergo against dependency injection.

> It can't be a static class. You can't pass a static class in a constructor, so you get very tight coupling to the static class in your consumers and the static class can't be used for late binding.

Static classes should only be used for pure methods. If it's a pure method, then yeah this is viable. However, given you're talking about constructor parameters, there's likely an expectation of state, which disproves that it's pure.

Statics cannot be mocked, but that's generally accepted as long as you back your pure logic with rigorous testing. As long as the tests pass, it's reasonable to use the real logic and assume that it's working as intended.

> It can't be any sort of C# function-holding object like a Func. These are almost as good as using instance class, but they have a major flaw. If you put a Func in a consumer's constructor, then the consumer must know how many arguments the Func takes in and their types. This is not true of an interface-backed instance class; If I take in an IObfuscatedFunctionCall in a consumer's constructor, then my consumer never needs to know if I've added more arguments to ObfuscatedFunctionCall's constructor.

This is a weak argument. Your argument rests solely on not liking that you have to change the specific `Func<>` generic types. It's an argument of "I don't like typing more", not one of logical consistence or algorithmic complexity.

If your method signature changes, you have to update your consumer anyway to account for the changed signature. Whether you also have to update the `Func<>` type is an irrelevant addition to that consideration.

This can be easily proven by creating a passthrough `Foo : Func<Bar, Baz>` wrapper. Your consumer of `Foo` doesn't need to explicitly type the `Func<>` parameters but it still needs to know about them in order to be able to exeute `this.myFoo`.

Arguments based on "I don't want to type more" are not valid arguments. Sometimes they align with good practice, but not always, and they should not be used as the driving argument.

> It can't be a delegate. Those have the exact same faults as Funcs.

Same argument as above.

> I can't imagine any way to make this a static method without encountering the same faults as what you get with static classes.

The "faults" of static classes are not inherent faults, they're misuses of static classes in the wrong scenario. Don't get me wrong, I'm not a frequent user of static classes, but they have their rightful place.

> What alternatives have I overlooked?

It's not so much that you've overlooked alternatives, but it's more that your observations are a bit too black-and-white and lack nuance, which is making you overstate your conclusions.

All of the listed approaches are valid in their own way, but you have to see which approach's pros and cons best matches your current scenario.

Comment: What you've said seems largely correct and I will think more on it. Your point about what "just a function" omits is very strong and worthy of expansion. However, I'm missing your point about `Func`s. You've said "_If your method signature changes, you have to update your consumer anyway to account for the changed signature_", but I never mentioned changing the method signature. I only mentioned changing the constructor of the class that holds the method.

Comment: @J.Mini If it's "just a function", then there is only the function argument, there are no separate constructor arguments. If you instead persist with distinguishing one from the other, them you've proven my point about needing separate lifecycles for the constructor arguments vs the method arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to hide `number1` and `number2` from consumers of this abstraction, you are left with `void Fn()`. This can be achieved in many languages using [closures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

```
let createSender = function(number1, number2) {
    return function() {
        fetch("/calculate", {
            method: "POST",
            body: `n1=${number1}&n2=${number2}`
        });
    };
};

let calculate = createSender(3, 9);

doSomething(23, calculate);
```

Now imagine for a moment `doSomething` is implemented as:

```
let doSomething = function(n, calculate) {
    if (n > 10) {
        calculate();
    }
};
```

From the perspective of `doSomething` the calculate parameter is just a function with no return value and no arguments — equivalent to your `void Execute()`. The dependencies of this function — number1 and number2 — are hidden using the closure created by the `createSender` function. In many ways, closures can be substituted for objects, and vice-versa. Even though your example does not return a value, this can be loosely considered [functional composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)).

This achieves late binding because you can call `doSomething` and pass it any function that takes no arguments and returns no value. This simple interface also achieves the lose coupling you desire because you pass the function as a parameter to `doSomething` rather than referencing a global name like you would with a static function.

Some additional reading:

- [Closures And Objects Are Equivalent](http://wiki.c2.com/?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent)
- ["Closures are poor man's objects and vice versa" - What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2497801)

---

As an aside, C# does have support for closures:

- [Local Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)
- [What are closures in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428617)
- Not to mention the `Func`s and `Action`s you turned down as options in your question.

Comment: @J.Mini, so use instance methods. In many languages functions are first-class citizens that can be passed around like any other value. Calling a static function might be tight coupling, but if you can pass mocks for all its dependencies, you should be fine for testing purposes. If you need polymorphism, then you need objects or function pointers/lambda expressions.

Comment: BTW, I removed `static` from the function signatures, since that seems to be muddying the waters.

Comment: So make it static again. You might be over-thinking this.

Comment: The very things you have ruled out *are* the alternatives. Not everything needs to be an object, and not all static functions imply bad coupling.

Comment: *"Every option that I've listed has disadvantages"* — correction: every option for solving every problem has disadvantages. Don't over think this. If the code you write is sufficiently easy to test, change, and reason about, choose the solution that fits your needs the best, because none of them are perfect.

Comment: My only other guess is closures.

Comment: @J.Mini: rewrote my answer. I think this more accurately addresses the problem.

Comment: Your rewrite makes good points. I presume this is F#? It might be worth expanding on your final point. If `Func`s can do what I want and I've somehow missed it, then that would be a valuable refutation to what I've claimed in the second point in the numbered list in my original question. I think it's clear even in my question that I wish that I could do this with `Func`s. Flater's answer suggests that there's some important point to be made about initialisation, which isn't usually done with `Func`s.

Answer (score 4):

> It can't be any sort of C# function-holding object like a `Func`. These are almost as good as using instance class, but they have a major flaw. If you put a `Func` in a consumer's constructor, then the consumer must know how many arguments the `Func` takes in and their types. This is not true of an interface-backed instance class; If I take in an `IObfuscatedFunctionCall` in a consumer's constructor, then my consumer never needs to know if I've added more arguments to `ObfuscatedFunctionCall`'s constructor.

This is how you instantiate `ObfuscatedFunctionCall`:

```
var myNumber1 = 35;
var myNumber2 = 36;
var serverTalker = new ServerTalker();
var obfuscatedFunction = new ObfuscatedFunctionCall(myNumber1, myNumber2, serverTalker);
```

... and then pass it whereever you want.
You can do the same with `delegate`/`Func`/`Action`:

```
var myNumber1 = 35;
var myNumber2 = 36;
var serverTalker = new ServerTalker();
Action nonObfuscatedFunction = () => 
{ 
    serverTalker.Send(myNumber1, myNumber2); 
};
```

In newer versions of C# you can even write the function in-place and don't have to wrap it in `Action`.

Functions and classes are not equivalent. Closures and classes are. `nonObfuscatedFunction` is not only a function, it's also a closure because it closes over its environment (uses the three arguments in its body without explicit references). The equivalent to `IObfuscatedFunctionCall` is **not**:

```
delegate void Execute(int n1, int n2, ITalkToServer t);
```

it's:

```
delegate void Execute();
```

And if you want to pass the closure's constructor somewhere for later instantiation, for example, to model factories, you can even do that:

```
delegate Execute Construct(int number1, int number2, ITalkToServer serverTalker);
// as Action/Func:
Func<int, int, ITalkToServer, Action>
```

Comment: yes exactly right i think

Answer (score 2):

There is some misplaced reasoning here. `ObfuscatedFunctionCall` only having one method isn't an issue. It doesn't break Inversion of Control to only hang one method off of it. Doing this does:

```
(new ObfuscatedFunctionCall(3,2,1)).Execute();
```

Doing that statically binds you just as much as a static method would. Classes give you a chance to build objects in one place and call methods in another place. They keep their data in a place that has a different lifetime.

Static functions are not, and never will be, the only way to express [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).  I've seen shops develop that habit. I don't approve of it. It's simply abusing a language feature by pretending it imposes constraints it doesn't. Static methods are static methods. They don't know what pure functions are. Please don't pretend one is the other.

Oh, and there's no such thing as a class design that will only ever have one method. I reserve the right to add `toString()` to them all.

Comment: I think this might be the key issue. "Obfuscated function call" classes aren't an anti-pattern. They're a way to separate construction from usage. What you need to do before deciding that it should "just be a function" is decide if you benefit from separating construction from usage. If you don't benefit from it, then you can consider options like static methods.

Comment: @J.Mini well said

Comment: *Oh, and there's no such thing as a class design that will only ever have one method*   =>  I had my trip to Oz.  In one code base I saw about a dozen "1-method class + unique `interface`" ... each  with exactly one use.

Answer (score 2):

I think where people are misunderstanding this question is in the assumption that you want to pass a function into your consuming class. You don't. You want to allow the consuming class to call a void, no parameters function, an `Action` and have that action perform work which is defined elsewhere.

This is simple

```
ConsumingClass
{
    ConsumingClass(Action func) {...}
    SomeMethod() 
    {
         this.func(); //run the passed in function
    }
}

Main()
{
    var number1 = 1;
    var number2 = 2;
    ITalkToSever serverTalker = new TalkToSever();
    Action func = () => { serverTalker.Send(number1, number2); };
    var myClass = new ConsumingClass(func);
    myClass.SomeMethod();
}
```

Your problem then comes around again when you what to use the standard .net core DI framework to inject the function.

Unfortunately the standard DI framework is missing the things you need to make it work

1. named dependencies

   As all no parameter void returning functions have the same signature, the DI framework wont know which to inject without this.
2. injecting Func into controllers

   It seems you will have to customise the DI framework to achieve this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736070/how-to-use-funct-in-built-in-dependency-injection

However. Other DI frameworks are available Unity for example. Or you could use multiple delegates all with the same Action style signature.

As you point out, this isn't great looking code. Its unclear why you are passing these functions around so its hard to say what a 'good' solution would be to the wide problem. But I think a better way would be

1. Pass a Func<t1,t2...,treturn> or delegate in

   Although this fails your "I don't want to change the method signature" test, you have to question why the calling code doesn't have parameters to send. The whole point of passing functions is that they *dont* have side effects. So really you want the calling code to do more work

ie.

```
SomeMethod()
{
    var calcResult = this.injectedFunc(a,b,c);
    this.serverTalker.Send(calcResult);
}
```

2. Use Event handlers. These have fallen out of fashion but would be the idiomatic way of passing in Actions

ie.

```
ConsumingClass
{
    public event EventHandler func

    SomeMethod() 
    {
        if(this.func != null) {
          this.func(); //run the passed in function
        }
    }
}

Main()
{
    var myClass = new ConsumingClass();
    myClass.func += func;
    myClass.SomeMethod();
}
void func(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serverTalker.Send(number1, number2); 
}
```

3. The way you are doing it now is fine.

   Your example function has data, the construction parameters. Its standard OOP to group that with the method in a class. These 'bad' objects which should be functions don't have state AND he's passing in parameters when he calls them!

   Even if you did have a 'pure' function, unless you know that all possible implementations will also be pure functions. You might still want to use a class. Just incase one function in 10 has state, or side effects, or would be to complex to write in a single function.

Comment: I've never seen the `IAction` interface before and what I'm finding on Google isn't what I'd expect. Do you have a link to its documentation?

Comment: ahh sorry i mean `Action` https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-action-delegate

Comment: I think this still has the issue discussed in point #2 of the numbered list in my question. If I decide to add a parameter to `var func`, then the list of input parameters to `ConsumingClass` must change. The same would not be true of the original `ObfuscatedFunctionCall`.

Comment: no, because just like Execute() the Action signature never has any parameters added to it. To add a "parameter" you change the function defintition. ie `func => () { return a + b;}}`

Comment: there, ive updated the code to match your example

Comment: @J.Mini have i understood and answered your question correctly?

Comment: It's certainly an answer. I'll have to think about if it's a good one. It certainly seems far from idiomatic C#, but it works.

Comment: idiomatic c# would probably use event handlers

Comment: updated with idiomatic methods

Answer (score 0):

Without arguing:

a. "*You can't pass a static class in a constructor*", since it's well known that instances of classes rather than classes are what it can be passed.

b. "*If you put a Func in a consumer's constructor*" since for described use case to achieve loose coupling and pass different values per consumer call, a new instance per call is required rather than an instance per consumer instance.

c. "*I think that an interface-backed instance is the only option*" since IoC is about whom instantiate the class rather than whom defines the type of it.

Apply the fundamental theorem of software engineering: "*We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection*" and the solution, termed "*instance per request*", is a static factory method called with the parameters used by the `ObfuscatedFunctionCall` instance it returns every time before the consumer it is called.

Comment: There are a few good points in here, but the formatting makes it difficult to read. Your entire answer is one long sentence. Consider adding some full stops, line breaks, or bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced video begins with The Zen of Python. I give a nod to a manifesto worthy of emulation in OO coding. Then the "obsfucated class" is displayed. As he pares it down to its essential one-line the "class" is proved to be the heretical Zen-ophobic poster child for *writing code*. However the presenter has made an error of mis-identifying an Object Oriented DESIGN pile of failure as merely poor writing.

Our class struggle session is just implementation creative writing trying to cram it somewhere, anywhere that will rationalize as coherent; all the while further making the lecture host's points.

For Uncle Bob's sake! Delete it and on your next design project put the functionality in an appropriate class so we have *increased cohesiveness and reduced coupling*  Now that is Oh, so OO.